# Magento 1.9 where is the method $this->getImage()? phpstorm couldn't trace

Tags: magento-1.9

File path: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php`

method `getImageUrl()`

the `$this-getImage()` cannot be traced by phpstorm

Any advice how to look for it? or my settings in phpstorm for magento 1.9 isn't covering important area?

[image]

Comment: Magento uses a ton of magic methods and other things which make IDEs unable to properly resolve classes and methods. Magicento is a PHPStorm plugin designed to overcome some of these issues. Maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` which in turn extends `Varien_Object`. The [Magento 1 Developer Guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-8.html) mentions the following about `Varien_Object`:

> The Varien_Object class defines the object all Magento Models inherit from. This is a common pattern in object oriented systems, and ensures you'll always have a way to easily add methods/functionally to every object in your system without having to edit every class file.
>
> Any Object that extends from Varien_Object has magic getter and setters that can be used to set data properties.

So the `getImage` method is very likely such a magic method that retrieves the data property `image` if it is set, otherwise it will return `null`. That method is not defined anywhere explicitly because it is a magic method and so PhpStorm cannot find it. Even if you have Magicento as mentioned by BlueC in the comment you won't be able to find the method.